# How paperclip returns the path to that file which is uploaded rather then path with file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip

Hi I am using Ruby on rails to load the assets on to the page with paperclip:

In paperclip by using

```
render file: @garment.xhtml_file.url
```

will return the path

> :`"/home/tukatech/rails_projects/live_tukagarments/public/system/xhtml_files/60/Cycle_Suit.xhtml?1545631909"`

But my requirement is upto :

> `"/home/tukatech/rails_projects/live_tukagarments/public/system/xhtml_files/60/Cycle_Suit.xhtml"`

not including the dust is there a way to do it in paperclip

Comment: You have used two rails tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5, but probably you are using only one version of rails. If so, which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using @garment.xhtml_file.path that will give you are required path

Comment: that will give the path to the file including the timestamp , I do not want that timestamp with full path. Thanks

Comment: @vidurpunj it will give the file path only without timestamp

Answer (score 0):

```
 url = "/home/tukatech/rails_projects/live_tukagarments/public/system/xhtml_files/60/Cycle_Suit.xhtml?1545631909"
```

do

```
url.split("?")[0]
```

for getting output

```
 "/home/tukatech/rails_projects/live_tukagarments/public/system/xhtml_files/60/Cycle_Suit.xhtml"
```

Comment: Thanks @vishal but I do not want to use split by "?"  because that can be present in file name itself.

Comment: What output are you getting if i you try .path ?

Comment: "/home/tukatech/rails_projects/live_tukagarments/public/system/xhtml_files/60/Cycle_Suit.xhtml?1545631909"